# Is a 401K taxed as regular income when the owner dies?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, inheritance

If an owner takes distributions from a 401K, it is taxed as regular income.

If the owner of the 401K dies (with no beneficiaries) the money is put into the estate of the deceased.   **Is it still taxed as regular income?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> the money is put into the estate of the deceased

The 401k account balance is not necessarily put into the estate of the deceased. It goes through the probate process, and may be delivered to heirs as appropriate based on the probate court decision.

Whoever ends up being allocated the account, will need to withdraw the balance within 10 years, and these withdrawals will be taxed as ordinary income (unless it is Roth 401k, in which case it will be after-tax withdrawals).

Comment: @littleadv  So there is no tax advantage to waiting...right?  The 401K could be closed now and put in the owner's estate.   Which when distributed to the heirs, will be taxed as regular income.

Comment: @SteveWellens meaning what exactly? If the future deceased closes the 401k now then they'll be the one's paying income taxes on the money. Why would they want to do that? What's the end goal?

Comment: @SteveWellens or are you an estate executor and asking whether it is wise to distribute the 401k to the estate and then distribute the estate to the heirs? If so - no, it is not at all wise. Estate will be taxed at much higher trust income tax rates than the individual heirs (which, depending on their personal situation and the amounts, may time the distributions and pay little to no tax).

Comment: And for a not very large 401k, pulling it all out at once by an heir likely means the incremental tax rate will be higher than it would be if taken out over several years.

Comment: @littleadv Ack, sorry. I should have read the question more closely. I'll delete the original comment.

Comment: @littleadv   The end goal?  To pay as little in taxes as legally possible.  It's not a large amount and their are several heirs.   Another goal is to make the estate as simple as possible to administer.

Comment: @SteveWellens understood. Estate paying income tax is **the worst**. Let the heirs deal with their own tax situation and optimize.